# Help on one specific binomial distribution question

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I am studying statistics and found the following problem.

> What is the probability that $2$ of the $10$ packets tested would turn out to be defective?

The problem should be solved using following formula $10C2 \cdot p^2  (1-p)^8$.

Now I am facing problem while trying to figure out the value of $p$.
If one packet is picked at random then the probability of getting one defective packet $= 0.5$. Hence I have put $p=0.5$ in the above question and calculated the solution.

But in the solution they used $p=0.05$. I am not sure why $p$ should be $0.05$. Can you please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you state the whole question from the problem?

Comment: This is the only statement. I just copied the problem and pasted here. After I submitted my answer they marked it as wrong and provided the solution considering p=0.05. Now I am unable to figure out why p=0.05.

Comment: But how can I answer the question if the statement does not give me $p$? The only problem here is the value of $p$, which is a parameter of the process being described in the question. What is the proportion of defective packages in the population? 50% or 5%? You said:
"If one packet is picked at random then the probability of getting one defective packet =0.5"
Why is the probability of getting one defective packet 0.5? It does not follow from the information you gave.

Comment: There are two unknowns $p$ and $\binom{10}{2}p^2(1-p)^8$.  You should have been given one to solve for the other.